# angular js adding two numbers issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code using angular js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function TodoCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.total = function () {
                return $scope.x + $scope.y;
            };

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div ng-app>
  <h2>Calculate</h2>

  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <form>
        <li>Number 1: <input type="text" ng-model="x" /> </li>
        <li>Number 2: <input type="text" ng-model="y" /> </li>
        <li>Total <input type="text" value="{{total()}}"/></li>       
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am able to do multiplication, division and subtraction but for addition, the code just concatenates the x and y values (i.e. if x = 3 and y = 4, the total is 34 instead of being 7)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If that is indeed the case then what is happening is the values that are being passed in for x and y are being treated as strings and concatenated. What you should do is convert them to numbers using `parseInt`

```
return parseInt($scope.x) + parseInt($scope.y);
```

or if you prefer brevity

```
return $scope.x*1 + $scope.y*1;
```

Comment: Isn't that something! Where can I learn more about this kind of brevity?

Comment: @mpora - Just through poking around I guess. I am not aware of a site that has all of the shortcuts displayed in a list. I got that one from this post about guid's: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2117523/1026459

Comment: Thanks, I am always looking for brevity.

Comment: What I wonder in this sample is, why does angular js know when to call the function total? I attached a debugger and it seems that it polls.

Comment: plus has precedence over bit-wise or so it should be:
    return ($scope.x|0) + ($scope.y|0);
i also thought it was the other way around.

Comment: Thanks, It works. Only `key+1` won't work. Only `parseInt(key)+1` works in angularJS controller.

Answer (score 7):

You want this:

```
   return parseFloat($scope.x) + parseFloat($scope.y);
```

`+` overrides string concatenation when you have 2 strings.  You'll need to cast them to integers or floats explicitly.  `-`,`*`,`/` will all cast to numbers if possible.

Comment: are they integers? if not that would be why.  What doesn't work about parseInt?

Answer (score 2):

That is because the concatenation has higher precedence over addition operation or the Plus (+) Operator.
Since, Minus Operator (-) works just fine , here is a Simple Hack!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function TodoCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.total = function () {
            //Subtracting a Zero converts the input to an integer number
            return (($scope.x - 0) + ($scope.y - 0));
        };

    }
</script>
```

You could as well do this:

```
<form>
    <li>Number 1: <input type="text" ng-model="x" /> </li>
    <li>Number 2: <input type="text" ng-model="y" /> </li>
    <li>Total <input type="text" value="{{(x-0) + (y-0)}}"/></li>       
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding floating numbers in correct way

```
 $scope.Total = parseFloat($scope.firstValue) + parseFloat($scope.secondValue);
 $scope.Total = parseFloat($scope.Total.toFixed(2));
```

The $scope.Total now will display correctly in the view if binding with `ng-model` is applied
for example if you have

```
$scope.firstValue = 10.01;
$scope.firstValue = 0.7;
```

`$scope.Total = parseFloat($scope.firstValue) + parseFloat($scope.secondValue);`

The variable `$scope.Total` will be `10.709999999999999` and this is not correct!
Adding with parseFloat will not be enough for a correct value.
But if you apply

`$scope.Total = parseFloat($scope.Total.toFixed(2));`

The value will result correctly: `$scope.Total = 10.71`

Be careful will floating point numbers in javascript

Comment: please add demo if possible

Answer (score 1):

Make input type as number, since it is addition operation

```
<input type="text" ng-model="x" />
<input type="text" ng-model="y" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To add two numbers together I would parse the string for Integers and check for null:

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.total = function() {
        var firstNum = parseInt($scope.firstNum) 
        var secondNum = parseInt($scope.secondNum);

        if (!firstNum)
            firstNum = 0;
        if (!secondNum)
            secondNum = 0;

        return firstNum + secondNum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to change the type of your input to "number", then, you will not need to parse it, angular will convert it automatically to interger. I did it and it works, without a scope, but only to declare your {{total}}