# The submit button not working AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

So basically wwhat I'm trying to do is take input of two numbers n1 and n2 and then print their sum all using angular. I have used bootstrap for styling. But i noticed nothing was happening so to check i added `alert()` function in the function to be called but still it's not getting accessed somehow. I dont know jQuery.

PS: when I use `text1+text2` it's concatinating the string instead of printing the sum

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">
  <head >
    <title>Trying Angular</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="form-inline" style="border: 2px solid blue; max-width:500px;" ng-controller="formCtrl as formCtrl" ng-submit="formCtrl.submit()">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Enter n1</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter the first number" ng-model="text1">
      <p>{{ text1}}</p>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Enter n2</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter the second number" ng-model="text2">
      <p >{{text2}}</p>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group"  style="display:block; margin:10px auto; margin-left:370px;">
      <input type="submit" class="form-control"  >
    </div>

     <p>  Your SUM of two numbers is ={{text1+text2}}</p>
   </form>

   <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
   <script  src="exp1.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my angular code:

```
(function(){
    var app=angular.module('store',[]);

    var n1=0;
    var n2=0;

    app.controller('formCtrl',function(){
          this.submit=function(){alert("successful");}; // <----- alert()
    });
})();
```

Comment: Try `ng-controller="formCtrl as formCtrl"`

Comment: It worked! thanks but i don't understand why was that needed ? I already named my controller formCtrl?

Comment: Your controller used the ControllerAs syntax - i.e. `this` but you had not used this in the HTML

Comment: So if i don't use 'this' is there any other way to call the same function?

Comment: Yes, see the answers below

Comment: To solve your problem of concatenating the string instead of adding 2 numbers (which are still strings btw): see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15648744/1945990

Comment: @mjwatts can a solution be available without using $scope for parsing?

Comment: my html is same but with this addition

`<p>  Your SUM of two numbers is ={{fc.parse(text1)+fc.parse(text2)}}</p>` and my js 




`this.parse=function(text){
            var changed=parseInt(text);
            return changed;

            alert("successful");

           };`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation for the ngController directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController), there are two ways to access the members of a controller:

1. Use the `as <scopeProperty>` syntax, and access it using the `<scopeProperty>` name:

```html
<form class="form-inline" style="border: 2px solid blue; max-width:500px;" ng-
      controller="formCtrl as fc" ng-submit="fc.submit()">
```

Here, `fc` is being declared as the name for the controller instance, and its properties are accessed with `fc.`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7L00bu8q/3/)

2. Inject `$scope` into the controller and add properties to that:

```js
app.controller('formCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
     $scope.submit = function(){alert("successful");};
}]);
```

```html
<form class="form-inline" style="border: 2px solid blue; max-width:500px;" ng-
      controller="formCtrl" ng-submit="submit()">
```

Here, the controller's properties are added to the `$scope` and this allows us to access them directly in the HTML without using the dot notation.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/u5pbjjeh/1/)

The page linked to above compares and contrasts the two approaches. You were not exactly using either, and that's why you were having trouble.

Comment: what does $scope does? I don't know jquery

Comment: `$scope` is not jQuery. It represents the scope of the controller. Please see the link I provided for more information.

Comment: @FossArduino have a look at https://egghead.io/articles/new-to-angularjs-start-learning-here too

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to add your submit code inside a function:

```
app.controller('formCtrl',[$scope, function('$scope'){

    $scope.submit = function() {
        alert('submit');
    };

}]);
```

then in your ng-submit directive use submit() as per [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) you can also use ng-change and ng-click directives to update the models then do whatever with the models.

**Further to the comments about accessing the data from the inputs:**
When you add the ng-model attribute to an input you are saying I would like data from this input to be stored in ng-models name. Adding this to an input: **ng-model="inputvalue.input1"** would enable you to store data kind of like the following:

```
inputvalue = {
    input1 : "Input value would go here"
}
```

note the names are the same for a reason.

You can then set up those objects to be stored/accessed inside the controller using $scope [look at the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D) on AngularJS website - take your time and get to know what's going on.

Comment: Thanks but how to access the values of the inputs? I don't know jquery at all.

Comment: You shouldnt need jquery, in fact it's quite confusing using the two frameworks side by side - a lot of what do using jquery is already available in Angular. The data from the inputs is stored in an object named in ng-model - I'll elaborate in my answer

Comment: @FossArduino The above doesn't involve jQuery. You would access your bound properties using `$scope.text1`, `$scope.text2`, etc.

Comment: @mjwatts Looks like you forgot to inject `$scope` into the controller.

Comment: @FossArduino Nobody is suggesting that you use jQuery.

Comment: but codeschool tutorial never uses scope that's why i don't know it

Comment: they simply use this.function

Comment: @FossArduino There's nothing preventing you from learning something that wasn't in the codeschool tutorial. CodeSchool uses the `as ...` syntax in their tutorials, and you were failing to use that.

Comment: But they use as format to asign an alias right? here i'm assigning the same name as the alias just to satisfy the syntax?

Comment: @FossArduino It's probably best not to think of the value after the `as` as an alias. It's more like giving the controller instance a name you can use to access it. If you don't use the `as ...`, there isn't a name you can use to access the controller (AFAIK).

Comment: In fact the alias is the property name